# Differentiate the expression

Tags: calculus

I am trying to differentiate the expression for voltage. And find the rate of change of the voltage after 9 seconds.

This is my expression:

$$v=60(1 - e^{-0.2t})$$

t is time in seconds.

I have read so much and still don't understand how to do it.

It just confuses me.

I have read examples with different expressions, but do not know which one to use.

An example of an expression I have read to use:

$$A = Pe^{rt}$$

But not sure if it correct to use that, or how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x))=g'(x)f'(g(x))$$
In your example,
$$f(x)=60(1-e^{x})$$
$$g(x)=-0.2x$$
And so
$$f'(x)=-60e^x$$
$$g'(x)=-0.2$$
and so, by the chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx} 60(1-e^{-0.2x})=-0.2\cdot-60e^{-0.2x}=12e^{-0.2x}$$

Comment: Thank you. I understand it better now. I will go back through the chain rule.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

$$v=60(1 - e^{-0.2t})=60-60e^{-0.2t}$$

Notice that derivative to a constant is $0$, and you could use the expression you read to the rest of the expression.

Comment: Thank you for your help.